# How to install different projects of a solution at different locations using single web setup project

Tags: web-setup-project

I have an asp.net MVC solution in VS 2010 which has multiple asp.net MVC web application projects inside it. My requirement is that each of these projects should be able to deploy independently on same/different servers. I have to deploy them using Web setup project. 
I don't want to create a separate web setup project for each MVC web application project.
Is it possible to create only one Web setup project and provide the target directory name for each project during installation? Or is there any other alternative to achieve the same?
For ex: if i have 3 different projects in the solution, i want to put the files of each project on different servers(server path needs to be given during installation). Is this possible using single Web setup project?

Alternatively can i create separate .msi file for different project but using the single Web setup project?

Thanks,
Manoj